# No method 'get' on backbone model save

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone for a reasonably complicated form. I have a number of nested models, and have been computing other variables in the parent model like so:

```
// INSIDE PARENT MODEL

computedValue: function () {
    var value = this.get('childModel').get('childModelProperty');
    return value;
}
```

This seems to work fine for keeping my UI in sync, but as soon as I call

```
.save()
```

on the parent model, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'
```

It seems that the child model kind of temporarily stops responding.

Am I doing something inherently wrong?

EDIT: The stack trace is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get' publish.js:90
Backbone.Model.extend.neutralDivisionComputer publish.js:90
Backbone.Model.extend.setNeutralComputed publish.js:39
Backbone.Events.trigger backbone.js:163
_.extend.change backbone.js:473
_.extend.set backbone.js:314
_.extend.save.options.success backbone.js:385
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

EDIT #2 in response to comment below:

There's something basic I'm still not getting. I replaced a few references to this.get('childModel')['childModelProperty'] and now I get things like
    'cannot read property childModelProperty of undefined.

I'm not yet pulling anything from the server, the parent model is just created like

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'models/childmodel'],    function($, _, Backbone, ChildModel) {
var ParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
   childModel : new ChildModel()
    }
```

Comment: try dropping the second .get down one line, so you can identify which call to get() is causing the error, by line number

Comment: can you include the stack trace of the error

Comment: I did some other checking and it's the second get() call.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the `childModel` stored in the attributes hash actually the child Model itself, or simply a copy of said child's attributes? In the latter case, you would of course want to grab the property directly: `this.get('childModel')['childModelProperty']`;

Comment: I think this is it. I wasn't paying attention to whether I was using the child model itself or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults` are only used when you create the model.  After save is called, it will call `set` which will overwrite childModel with a simple javascript object.  As I see it you have a couple options:

1) use [Backbone.Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/)

2) override `set` in each parent model to update the existing child model (or create it) something like the following:

```
children:{
    childModel: ChildModel
}
set: function (key, value, options) {
                var attrs;
                if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
                    attrs = key;
                    options = value;
                } else {
                    attrs = {};
                    attrs[key] = value;
                }

                _.each(this.children, function (childType, name) {
                    if (!attrs.hasOwnProperty(name))
                        return;

                    //assume the child is just a model--not a collection
                    var newValue = attrs[name];
                    delete attrs[name];
                    var isModel = this[name] && this[name].set;
                    if (isModel && newValue) {
                        this[name].set(newValue, options);
                    }
                    else if (newValue) {
                        this[name] = new childType(newValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        delete this[name];
                    }

                    this.trigger('change:' + name);

                }, this);

                return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);             

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Backbone Relational - its exactly what I was looking for. Any idea whether it works with Model Binder? https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

Comment: I'm not sure about model binder.  I haven't used that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your childModel does not contains a Backbone.Model, like you were assigned other kind of object.

To avoid the error do this(and also in your console you will get helpful information about the value of that wrong childModel):

```
computedValue: function () {
    var value;
    if( this.get('childModel') instanceof Backbone.Model ){
        value = this.get('childModel').get('childModelProperty');
    }else{
        console.log('This is weird, childModel is not a Backbone.Model', this.get('childModel') );
    }
    return value;
}
```