# Backbone JS - JSON response recognized as actual Backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using backbone with some nested models. I have a bunch of change handlers on the parent and child models for UI updating (simplified version below). The problem I have is that as soon as I call save() on the parent model and the JSON comes back from the server, the child model data is updated, but it is no longer recognized as a Backbone model, and my handlers all fail.

```
ChildModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        property: "property"           
    }
});

ParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        childModel: new ChildModel()           
    },
    url : "resturl",
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind('change:childModel', this.changeHandler, this);
    },             
    changeHandler: function () {
       var child = this.get('childModel');
       if(child instanceof Backbone.Model){
         alert("is a backbone model");
       } else {
         alert("is not a backbone model")
       }
    }
});

var parent = new ParentModel();
parent.save()
```

When parent.save() is called, the model gets updated, but "is not a backbone model" gets alerted.
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my answer to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364615/737318) question.  I think it's related:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368225/737318

If that's not helpful, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll dive into this tomorrow and let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

Consider overriding the parse method and update the childModel there instead of in other.  methods. This is appropriate for saving bound events for model updates.

```
parse: function ( response, xhr ) {
    // don't update the models childData attribute
    if ( this.get('childModel') instanceof ChildModel ) {

        this.get('childModel').set( response.childData );
    } else {
       this.set({ childModel: new childModel( response.childData );
    }
    delete response.childData;
    return response;
}
```